# Rails: refresh page without hitting application during development

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm a front end developer. I often frequently need to reload the HTML and CSS of a page, without wanting to change any of the Controller-level data. I want to take the same data from the controller each time, with updated HTML/CSS.

I already use LiveReload to update my CSS on the fly.

This is particularly for "POST"'d views, where I don't want to post data over and over in order to see the HTML "thank you" page that comes afterwards.

Comment: One way is to (empty) the HTML and (append) the new back in. ($.("#mydivsection").empty();) -- ($.("#mydivsection").append(newhtml);)

Comment: @Tasos Is this a draft of an answer? Where would the OP get `newhtml` from if not from Rails?  @WillTaylor What disadvantages do you find in POSTing your request over and over again?

Comment: @dcorking not sure M8, rails went passed me, i only noticed the HTML and CSS portion :))

Comment: It would be nice if there was an HTML version of the [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) browser plugin that might allow the asker to repeatedly post his requests when he updates his page templates. Perhaps there is.

Comment: @dcorking Hypothetically it might be adding a line to a database, but the honest answer is that I like to get my page reload when developing to sub 1-second so that I can edit and see the response faster.

Comment: You may want to look at your development environment, because IMHO the repeated POSTs should not take more than 1 second. Does it happen on all your projects? Meanwhile, no harm in this question to find a way to only render your template.

Answer (score 0):

< meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600" / >

Add the meta tag on the header part of you html. The page will be reloaded every 10 minutes automatically!